App producing 2 messages for only 1 input
I'm trying to debug a problem in our production Kafka Streams app. The (simplified) topology looks something like this
builder.stream("input").groupByKey().reduce(
  (agg, val) -> "bar",
  Materialized.as("saved_store")
);

99% of our incoming messages on the "input" topic seem to work fine, but I found some cases that didn't. I see a single message for a particular key 123 in "input"
"123": "foo"

but when I look at the private Kafka topic that "saved_store" is materializing to, there are two messages there and both of them look like
"123": "bar"

What could be causing this? I would expect the saved store to only have a single message AND for value to be "foo", since the reducer is not supposed to be called when the key is seen for the first time.

Did you try disable caching to remove one moving piece?


look at the private Kafka topic that "saved_store" is materializing to,

That's the wrong way to view a store. Compacted topics back stores. Compacted topics do not guarantee unique keys within an open segment, before a log cleaner thread runs
"Uncompacted' topics Vs compacted topics

I understand they don't guarantee compaction, but why does that matter here? My understanding was that there should be nothing to compact, there should only be 1 message in the store to begin with.

The store is a view. Only it has no duplicates. The topic is not the same as the store. Use Interactive Queries to scan the state store. Don't consume the topic for that
